# unexpected extra semi-colon

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, styled-components

I am getting this eslint warning and I do not know how to fix it. This is my css

```
const StyledLabel = styled(P)`
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: ${spacing.override(6)};
  ${({ theme, selected }) =>
    selected && `border: 1px solid ${theme.primary.black};`};

  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid ${theme.primary.black};
  }
`;
```

The error underline shows up below block for line display: inline-block

[image: extra semi-colon warning]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is waring?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with ESLint, but this is a classic case of a tool pointing you to the wrong line for an error. When a tool is giving you an error that looks so wrong on the surface, it's generally a good idea to re-evaluate the surrounding code and manually verify that it's correct.

In this instance, the extra semicolon is actually on this statement:

```
${({ theme, selected }) =>
  selected && `border: 1px solid ${theme.primary.black};`};
```

When it gets interpreted at run time, it will evaluate to something like:

```
border: 1px solid black;;
```

You might have put that second semicolon in there as a reflex for finishing a JavaScript statement, but it's actually plain text at that point. For some reason when you moved that line up for your answer you ended up removing the extra character and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the dynamic css attribute to the top makes the error go away.

```
const StyledLabel = styled(P)`
  ${({ theme, selected }) =>
    selected && `border: 1px solid ${theme.primary.black};`}
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: ${spacing.override(6)};

  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid ${theme.primary.black};
  }
`;
```

[image: screenshot of the updated code showing no error lines]

Comment: Moving it wasn't the fix. Look at the end of ${theme.primary.black};`} in your answer vs the code you posted. That's where you extra semi-colon was located. Also, please don't post images of code as the only source of the code. This answer is not helpful for people with screen readers.